# SpringBatch Sharing Large Amounts of Data Between Steps

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a need to share relatively large amounts of data between job steps for a spring batch implementation. I am aware of `StepExecutionContext` and `JobExecutionContext` as mechanisms for this. However, I read that since these must be limited in size (less than 2500 characters). That is too small for my needs. In my novice one-step `Spring Batch` implementation, my single step job is as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


    private static final String GET_DATA =
    "    SELECT " +
    "stuffA, " +
    "stuffB, " +
    "FROM STUFF_TABLE " +
    "ORDER BY stuffA ASC";

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<StuffDto> databaseCursorItemReader(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<StuffDto>()
                .name("cursorItemReader")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .sql(GET_DATA)
            .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(StuffDto.class))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    ItemProcessor<StuffDto, StuffDto> databaseXmlItemProcessor() {
        return new QueryLoggingProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<StuffDto> databaseCursorItemWriter() {
        return new LoggingItemWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step databaseCursorStep(@Qualifier("databaseCursorItemReader") ItemReader<StuffDto> reader,
    @Qualifier("databaseCursorItemWriter") ItemWriter<StuffDto> writer,
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("databaseCursorStep")
            .<StuffDto, StuffDto>chunk(1)
        .reader(reader)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job databaseCursorJob(@Qualifier("databaseCursorStep") Step exampleJobStep,
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("databaseCursorJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(exampleJobStep)
            .end()
            .build();
    }
}
```

This works fine in the sense that I can successfully read from the database and write in the writer step to a loggingitemwriter like this:

```
public class LoggingItemWriter implements ItemWriter<StuffDto> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingItemWriter.class);

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends StuffDto> list) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Writing stuff: {}", list);
    }
}
```

However, I need to be able to make available that `StuffDto` (or equivalent) and it's data to a second step that would be performing some processing against it rather than just logging it.

I would be grateful for any ideas on how that could be accomplished if you assume that the step and job contexts are too limited. Thanks.

Comment: You store them in some temporary repository, like a database or filesystem?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that hopefully conveys in the context of springbatch

Comment: Just create a composite writer that does logging and then the analyzing. Basically you shoehorned logging into a seperate step. Heck you could even use an `ItemListener` or `StepListener` for that and log the written items (which would probably be more suiteable for the task).

Comment: You defined an item processor but you did not set it on the step. Is that intended? `performing some processing against it rather than just logging it`: You can implement that processing in the item processor. Are you sure you need a second step for the processing?

Comment: @M.Deinum , thanks. would it be possible to explain how I can share data for a second step using an itemlistener or steplistener? thank you.

Comment: Don't. As stated you are splitting something in 2 steps which you shouldn't split. You shouldn't store data in an item listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to write the data in the database or filesystem, one way to achieve the same is like below:

1. Create your own job context bean in your `config` class having the required properties and annotated it with `@JobScope`.
2. Implement `org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet` interface to your reader, processor and writer classes. If you want more control over steps you can also implement `org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener` with it.
3. Get your own `context` object using `@Autowire` and use the setter-getter method of it to store and retrieve the data.

Sample Code:

**Config.java**

```
@Autowired
private Processor processor;

@Autowired
private Reader reader;

@Autowired
private Writer writer;

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
     
@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Bean
@JobScope
public JobContext getJobContexts() {
    JobContext newJobContext = new JobContext();
    return newJobContext;
}

@Bean
public Step reader() {
      return stepBuilderFactory.get("reader")
        .tasklet(reader)
        .build();
     }

@Bean
public Step processor() {
      return stepBuilderFactory.get("processor")
        .tasklet(processor)
        .build();
     }

@Bean
public Step writer() {
      return stepBuilderFactory.get("writer")
        .tasklet(writer)
        .build();
     }


public Job testJob() {
      
      return jobBuilderFactory.get("testJob")
        .start(reader())
        .next(processor())
        .next(writer())
        .build();
     }

//Below will start the job
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void starJob(){
        
        Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<>();
        confMap.put("time", new JobParameter(new Date()));
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(confMap);
        monitorJobLauncher.run(testJob(), jobParameters);
        
}
```

**JobContext.java**

```
private List<StuffDto> dataToProcess = new ArrayList<>();
private List<StuffDto> dataToWrite = new ArrayList<>();

//getter
```

**SampleReader.java**

```
@Component
public class SampleReader  implements Tasklet,StepExecutionListener{
        @Autowired
        private JobContext context;
       
      @Override
      public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    //logic that you need to perform before the execution of this step.
      }
    
    @Override
      public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    //logic that you need to perform after the execution of this step.
      }
    
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext){
     // Whatever code is here will get executed for reader.
     //  Fetch StuffDto object from database and add it to jobContext 
   //dataToProcess list.
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

**SampleProcessor.java**

```
   @Component
   public class SampleProcessor  implements Tasklet{
    
       @Autowired
       private JobContext context;
    
        @Override
        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext){
        
         // Whatever code is here will get executed for processor.
        // context.getDataToProcessList();
       // apply business logic and set the data to write.

return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
```

Same ways for the `writer` class.

**Note**: Please note here that here you need to write database-related boilerplate code on your own. But this way you can have more control over your logic and nothing to worry about context size limit. All the data will be in memory so as soon as operation done those will be garbage collected. I hope you get the idea of what I willing to convey.

To read more about `Tasklet` vs `Chunk` read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-tasklet-chunk).

Comment: thank you for your detailed example. I am attempting to implement it now. Does the writer require any particular implementations (for instance, you had: "public class SampleReader  implements Tasklet,StepExecutionListener" for reader and "public class SampleProcessor  implements Tasklet" for processor. thanks

Comment: Yes, the implementation of `Tasklet` is mandatory. You may or may not implement `StepExectuionListener` it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks. Saurabh. I was able to use custom job context with JobScope as yo suggested above to accomplish what I needed to do. My setup is different than your example but the key was custom job context with JobScope. thanks again.

Comment: @Saurabh Why is the implementation of Tasklet mandatory? Can't JobScope not be used in the Chunk? I'm facing similar issue where I need to process data based on the data written by first Step's writer to make additional reads on secont Step's reader. Could you perhaps help me with my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757616/spring-batch-pass-data-from-writer-to-next-job-or-step. Thanks