# How to pool partitions in spring-batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Requirement:

1. Multiple files must be processed and mapped to entities
2. Collect a batch of N entities
3. Flush it to DB // The bottleneck

Current implementation:

`MultiResourcePartitioner` to read multiple files and `TaskExecutor` to make it multithreaded.

```
    Step s1 = sbf.get("file-db")
            .<Person, Person>chunk(1500)
            .reader(reader())
            .writer(jdbcWriter())
            .build();

    Step master = sbf.get("master-step")
            .listener(stepExecutionListener())
            .partitioner("master", partitioner())
            .step(s1)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
```

The problem:

Persisting to database only the entries from single file in each thread is inefficient. Is there a possibility to pool the entities in some data sink BEFORE committing to DB using built-in spring-batch functionality?
Or is the only way to achieve this is to push entities to a simple Queue and then read from it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63566381/12013107 may help

Comment: @Saurabh Maybe it would be possible to use a custom partitioner to create batches of files, that then would be processed in a Tasklet.

Answer (score 0):

The "workaround" I found was implementing a custom `Partitioner`, similar to `MultiResourcePartitioner`, and push a list of file names to `ExectionContext`.